# Codeigniter 3 - problem with submitting form values to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am a beginner of Codeigniter 3. I am trying to submit two form values in a view. Here is the code:

```
<?php


class User extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_logged'])){

             redirect("auth/login","refresh");
        }
    }

    public function profile(){

        $this->load->view('profile');
    }

    public function members(){
        if ($this->input->post('promote')!==FALSE){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Userpromote','required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

                $data = array(

                    'subadmin' => $_POST['username']        

                );

                $this->db->insert('sub', $data);

                redirect("user/members", "refresh");
            }

        } elseif ($this->input->post('demote')!==FALSE){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('subdemote','Userdemote','required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

                $data2 = $_POST['subdemote'];

                $this->db->delete('sub', array('subadmin' => $data2 ));

                redirect("user/members", "refresh");

            }
        }

        $this->load->view('members');
    }

    public function products(){

        $this->load->view('products');
    }

}
```

But problem is, only 'promote' part works, but the 'demote' portion doesn't. If i erase the 'promote' part, the 'demote' park work fine. Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a logic problem. You have the 'demote' code on a else if block, which means once the if statement is satisfied the else if won't be reached at all. Also you are using redirect on the end of the statements, which means you'll be redirected on that moment and the rest of the script won't be executed. You might try two sepparate if's like this:

```
public function members(){
    if ($this->input->post('promote')!==FALSE){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Userpromote','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

            $data = array(

                'subadmin' => $_POST['username']        

            );

            $this->db->insert('sub', $data);

            //redirect("user/members", "refresh");
        }

    } 
    if ($this->input->post('demote')!==FALSE){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subdemote','Userdemote','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

            $data2 = $_POST['subdemote'];

            $this->db->delete('sub', array('subadmin' => $data2 ));

            //redirect("user/members", "refresh");

        }
    }

    $this->load->view('members');
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you're getting the expected values for promote e demote?

Comment: yes i checked. if there is both, it doesn't work. If either one of those is erased, other works fine.